# Return opposite values from a pandas Series that has two unique values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

Given a Series with two unique values, what is the most efficient way to get a Series with the element-wise opposite values? Here is an example:

```
ser = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a'])
```

I am looking for a function to be applied to `ser`, returning:

```
0    b
1    a
2    b
```

**EDIT:** Also, how would the solution be ammended if there are null values. That is, if

```
ser = pd.Series(['a', 'b', np.nan , 'a'])
```

and we would like to get:

```
0    b
1    a
2    np.nan
3    b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.unique` to get a handy inverse array.

```
v = ser.values
u, i = np.unique(v, return_inverse=True)
```

If there are truly only 2 unique values, then you can do this.

```
pd.Series(u[1 - i], ser.index)

0    b
1    a
2    b
dtype: object
```

---

## How It Works

The inverse array is intended to allow you to recreate your passed array, `v` in our case, by slicing the unique values `u` with our inverse `i`.  Since `u` only has 2 values, those values will be `0` and `1`.  So when we slice `u[i]`, we get `array(['a', 'b', 'a'], dtype=object)`.  But we can get the ***opposite*** with `u[1 - i]` yields `array(['b', 'a', 'b'], dtype=object)`

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to adjust for nans? As I added in the edit

Comment: @splinter this would be better as another question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do an element by element on the series using apply:

**Code:**

```
ser = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a'])
print(ser.apply(lambda x: 'a' if x == 'b' else 'b'))
```

**Results:**

```
0    b
1    a
2    b
dtype: object
```